# Boundedness of composite functions

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are defined for all $x$.  Prove if true or give a counterexample if false:
>
> $f(x)$ is bounded implies $g(f(x))$ is bounded.

How may I approach this proof?

Comment: By the way, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to look at sin(x) cos(x) which are bounded composed with an unbounded functions.  The result of which are always bounded.

Comment: If you choose $f=\sin$, then for $g$ to be unbounded it will have to be discontinuous, which is fine. But if you want $g$ to be continuous, try a rational function or an inverse trig function for $f$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $g(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x, & x \ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0,\end{cases}$ and $f(x) = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your favorite $f$. What is its range? Is there a $g$ that is unbounded on the range of $f$? Or is that impossible?